Linkage between the cities of the plain and the philistine cities
There are 5 principal Philistine towns
Gaza, Ashdod, Ashkelon, Gath and Ekron (mentioned in Joshua)
There are 5 "cities of the plain" Sodom, Gomorrah, Adah, Zeboim, and Tzoar
Do any traditional sources make a connection between the two groups of cities?
Bonus Purim question: connect the above to Lawrence, Cedarhurst, Inwood, Hewlett, and Woodmere

וטינק כנגד כלם!
